# Excel TEXT format rounding issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2003

I am taking a string from a cell with my formula, and I need to output it (divided by 100 to show the PENCE) in the format "0.00" *with the quotes*!

For example:
975 becomes "9.75"

So I am using this formula:

```
TEXT(MID(C:C,17,FIND("_ _",C:C,12)-18)/10,"0.00")
```

and in the cell I expect to see **9.75** but it is being rounded, and I get 9.70.

Here is the source data (in column C":

```
323868_01064838_975_ _16092014_1.pdf
```

here is the complete formula including the TEXT conversion:

```
=IF(C:C<>"", """" & TEXT(MID(C:C,17,FIND("_ _",C:C,12)-18)/10,"0.00") & """","")
```

so what am I getting wrong here?

I need this so I can output it in csv format with the quotes for loading into another system.

Thanks for showing me what I am missing.
Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "-18" to "-17" and divide by 100. E.g.

`TEXT(MID(C:C,17,FIND("_ _",C:C,12)-17)/100,"0.00")`

Your original `MID()` formula was only returning 97, not 975, so dividing by 10 gave you 9.7

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the length and placement of the extraneous digits is fairly static but here is an alternate formula that will compensate for extra numbers here and there.

```
=CHAR(34)&0.01*TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_",REPT(" ",99)),199,99))&CHAR(34)
```

[image]